# How to deploy Azure Application Insights to a Production Environment via Ansible

Tags: azure, ansible

I have access in the Azure portal to create App Insights for my Dev and Staging environments that are in the same subscription.  However, our production subscriptions don't allow direct configuration and all resources have to be deployed via pipelines utilizing Ansible.   What is the role name needed to create Azure Application Insights via ansible/.yaml script?  What other information is needed?  I suspect you will need the connection string, subscription ID, resource group, environment, and location at a minimum.

Thank You
Robert G.